# download flash video using php readfile

Tags: php, flash, readfile

i am trying to download flv video to the flash player using PHP's readfile() function, using this i can hide the location of the file. i tried these codes but jw player don't work, file can downloaded separately but it don't work with the player.

```
<?php

$file = '/vid/myvideo.flv';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: video/x-flv');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myvideo.flv' );
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-length: '.filesize($file));

flush();
@readfile($file) or die("File not found.");
?>
```

when i transfer .swf it works file, but path of the file is visible.

is it possible to download flv file to flash player using readfile() function.

Comment: What do you mean by "the path of the file is visible"? Visible where?

Comment: path of the flv file in client side

Comment: Where exactly is it showing up?

Comment: it will not work with the player because the player needs the path . what you ask for is possible, but IMHO you would need to use another player, or write your own ..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **readfile**, try using **fread**. This is the way that I am doing it currently. It works on my system with jwplayer. I used  [this link](http://www.therealtimeweb.com/index.cfm/2005/11/2/Streaming-flv-video-via-PHP-take-two) as a reference.

Here's some example code:

```
//create the header
header("Content-Type: video/x-flv");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
//open the file
$fh = fopen($file, "rb");
ob_end_clean();
//start sending the file
while (!feof($fh)) {
    print(fread($fh, 8192));
}
//the file has been completely sent. close the file.
fclose($fh);

?>
```

Then when you create your jwplayer, here is the code for that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
          flashplayer: "player.swf", 
          file: "/getFlv.php", //for this example, getFlv.php is located at www.domain.com/getFlv.php
          provider:'http'
     });
 });
```